# Amazon RDS load balancing not working with mysql.createPool in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-rds

I have implemented load balancing in read database connection like when read db load increased to 60% it will initiate a new read database for balancing load on database but
When I see from AWS developer console dashboard all API calls It will initate new read database instance but most of the API's calls load took placed on database 1 upto 90 percent but like 10 req /sec and on read DB instance 2 1 to 5% database is used like 1req /sec
it should divided API request on both database equaly but It wont work
This issue is because mysql.createPool will not close connection from database 1 (createPool will reuse its opened connections) so that other API calls can move to second database instance.

To solve this problem I had changed mysql.createPool with mysql.createConnection on Each API calls
I had created 2 middleware
1-for createConnection
2-for connection.end()

whenever a request comes in middleware 1 calls and create new connection and on request finish middleware 2 will call which will end the connection. this solution has solved my problem of load balancing but a new issue takes place I have face to many database connection issues with this method

does anyone have a proper solution who has faced this issue or can help?

Sample Code :

```
var readDB = mysql.createConnection({
database: process.env.READ_DB_DATABASE,
host: process.env.READ_DB_HOST,
user: process.env.READ_DB_DB_USER,
password: process.env.READ_DB_DB_PASSWORD,
charset: "utf8mb4"
});
utils.js
async onFinish(req, res, next) {
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
try {
let readDB = req.readDB;
const dbEnd = util.promisify(readDB.end).bind(readDB);
const response = await dbEnd();
resolve(response);
} catch (error) {
reject(error);
}
});
}



app.js


/**
* middleware for create connection and end connection on finish
*/
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
try {
const readDB = await utils.readDBCreateConnection();
req.readDB = readDB;
res.on("finish", function () {
console.log("onFinish called");
utils.onFinish(req, res, next);
});
next();
} catch (error) {
res.status(error.status || 500).send({
code: 500,
message: error.message || `Internal Server Error`,
});
}
});


/**
* Code to initialice routing
*/
require("./modules/v2-routes")(app); // v2 app routes
```

Comment: are you using reader endpoint of the database cluster or instance endpoint?

Comment: reader end point see above sample code

Comment: As you mentioned, mysql.createPool will not close connection from database 1 (createPool will reuse its opened connections). Once i faced this issue as well. So i resolved by destroying the connection.

Comment: I think This issue of to many connection will be persist even when I try to destroy pool.
let me check